# Copy Text on Input Field with the help of Jquery on more than one input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

Hi it seems, you all would get the problem which I'm facing from the picture I have attached. I will share my Html Code with you. Please help me out with the jsfiddle :). All helps will be highly appreciated. Thank you all in advance

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Where are you starting from</label>
            <input type="text" name="start[]" class="form-control" placeholder="ex: Banglore">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Where do you want to go</label>
            <input type="text" name="destination[]" class="form-control dest" placeholder="ex: Some Other Places">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group multiple-form-group">
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 pad-left-0">
            <input type="text" name="start[]" class="form-control start" placeholder="ex: Intermediate place"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 pad-right-0">
            <input type="text" name="destination[]" class="form-control dest" placeholder="ex: Intermediate place"/>
        </div>
        <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-add">+
        </button></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

    (function ($) {
        $(function () {

            var addFormGroup = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
                var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');
                var $formGroupClone = $formGroup.clone();

                $(this)
                        .toggleClass('btn-default btn-add btn-danger btn-remove')
                        .html('–');

                $formGroupClone.find('input').val('');
                $formGroupClone.insertAfter($formGroup);

                $formGroupClone.attr('id', 'test' + (parseInt(/test(\d+)/.exec($(this).attr('id'))[1], 10)+1) ).appendTo('#main')

                var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
                if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') <= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
                    $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            };

            var removeFormGroup = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
                var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');

                var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
                if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') >= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
                    $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', false);
                }

                $formGroup.remove();
            };

            var countFormGroup = function ($form) {
                return $form.find('.form-group').length;
            };

            $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', addFormGroup);
            $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', removeFormGroup);

        });
    })(jQuery);

    $(function() {                                       // <== Doc Ready
        $(".dest").change(function() {                  // When the email is changed
            $('.start').val(this.value);                  // copy it over to the mail
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event delegation to bind a handler to dynamically-created elements. And you need to use DOM navigation functions to find the `.start` field related to the `.dest` that the user filled in.

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).on("change", ".dest", function() {
        $(this).closest(".form-group").next().find(".start").val(this.value);
    });
});

(function($) {
  $(function() {

    var addFormGroup = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
      var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');
      var $formGroupClone = $formGroup.clone();

      $(this)
        .toggleClass('btn-default btn-add btn-danger btn-remove')
        .html('–');

      $formGroupClone.find('input').val('');
      $formGroupClone.insertAfter($formGroup);

      $formGroupClone.attr('id', 'test' + (parseInt(/test(\d+)/.exec($(this).attr('id'))[1], 10) + 1)).appendTo('#main')

      var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
      if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') <= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
        $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', true);
      }
    };

    var removeFormGroup = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
      var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');

      var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
      if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') >= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
        $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', false);
      }

      $formGroup.remove();
    };

    var countFormGroup = function($form) {
      return $form.find('.form-group').length;
    };

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', addFormGroup);
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', removeFormGroup);

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>Where are you starting from</label>
      <input type="text" name="start[]" class="form-control" placeholder="ex: Banglore">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>Where do you want to go</label>
      <input type="text" name="destination[]" class="form-control dest" placeholder="ex: Some Other Places">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group multiple-form-group">
  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 pad-left-0">
      <input type="text" name="start[]" class="form-control start" placeholder="ex: Intermediate place" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 pad-right-0">
      <input type="text" name="destination[]" class="form-control dest" placeholder="ex: Intermediate place" />
    </div>
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-add">+
        </button></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Friend, thanks for your kind reply, but the function above is not working. It is not even copying the text. please do check it, if you have left in mistake in writing it. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your HTML. There seem to be lots of DIVs with `class="form-group"`, all nested inside each other. I can't figure out the relationship between the `dest` and the `start` that it should fill in. There's no unique class for the outermost `form-group`, which I think is the one I need to find with `.closest`.

Comment: Hi Friend, I can understand you, I have made the changes now, and removed unnecessary form-groups. Please check it out now and let me know where I'm wrong :-). Thank you

Comment: I still don't understand it very well. I see two `dest` fields in the HTML, but only one `start` field. When changing the `dest` field, how does it find the related `start` field?

Comment: Hi, I don't want to copy the text to the first text box, so I have mentioned the class `start` over there in first text box. Thats it, I want to copy the texts of first `dest` class into first `start` class filed. 2nd in 2nd and 3rd in 3rd and so on, Hope I'm not confusing you. Thanks

Comment: I've fixed it. I was copying to the previous DIV, but it should be copying this dest to the start in the next DIV.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working like a charm :-) . You are king of Javascript :-) @Barmar Thumbs up for you !!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91807/discussion-between-siddharth-and-barmar).